# "How to create a random variable clickid in php?"

Tags: php

I have a large amount of traffic and click on an ad at the same time. I need to create a random value to make the value of those clicks and not be duplicated. I tried many random ways but there was still a duplicate problem.

PHP 5

```
$random=bin2hex(mt_rand());
$clickid=md5($random);
```

I want clickid is not duplicate when large amount of traffic and click on an ad at the same time.

Comment: Are you looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about just concatenate multiple mt_rand()?

```php
$id = mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand();
```

If you need a *minimum length* unique id, you need to save the previous id in some database and get the increased counter in the transaction.

Comment: thank you so much. i am using this code and i think it is working fine. $rand1=mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand();
$rand2 = microtime();
$idclick=md5($rand1.$rand2);

Answer (score -1):

Use [microtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) as the value.
Unless you have sick amounts of traffic then it should be fine.
Microtime is a float value of the Unix time and the microseconds.
That means unless you have thousands of page requests each seconds it should give each one a unique number.

Usage:

```
$clickid = microtime();
```

Comment: thank you so much. i am using this code and i think it is working fine. $rand1=mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand();
$rand2 = microtime();
$idclick=md5($rand1.$rand2);

Comment: Why do you insist on the md5?

Comment: Andreas, i want clickid have both numbers and letters.

Comment: But MD5 means you can't be sure it's unique. MD5 can produce the same output with two different inputs.

Comment: Andreas, thank you. Because i don't understand about php. I need unique and both letter and number and about 15-20 characters.(exp : f967861763f8c44). Can you help me a code to creat it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I have this function which is often used by publishers and should do the job. It also relies on user's browser. Here you go:

```
function getClickId(){
    $p = dechex(rand()&15);
    $vid = hash('crc32b', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? $p, false);
    $clid = $vid.dechex(str_replace('.', '', microtime(true)));
    $clid = (strlen($clid) % 2 == 0) ? $clid : $p.$clid;
    $clid = bin2hex(random_bytes((24-strlen($clid))/2)).$clid;
    return $clid;
}
$clickid = getClickId();
echo $clickid.PHP_EOL; //contains only hexadecimal characters [0-9a-f] as you probably wanted to
echo strlen($clickid); //output is always 24 characters long
```